# Strange Behavior on WCF InstanceContextMode.Single + ConcurrencyMode.Single

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf

I have a WCF Service like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class MyWcfService
{
    public void StartIt()
    {
        MyWorkManager mgr = new MyWorkManager(new MyWorker());
        mgr.StartWorker();
    }
}
```

MyWrokManger's StartWorker method just starts a new thread with the start method pointed to MyWorker's StartWork method. Here's the MyWorker class:

```
public class MyWorker
{
    public void StartWork()
    {
        Mylogger.Log("Starting work...");

        // Call a long running method
        LongRunningMethod();

        Mylogger.Log("Completed work.");
    }

    private void WorkerMethod()
    {
        Mylogger.Log("Starting WorkerMethod()...");

        // do something here

        Mylogger.Log("Completed WorkerMethod().");
    }
}
```

I then use my client to call the service twice in a loop and here's what I see in the log (sorted by timestamp):

```
Invocation     ThreadID     Message
=================================================
1              5            Starting work...
2              7            Starting work...   
2              7            Starting WorkerMethod()...
1              5            Starting WorkerMethod()...
2              7            Completed WorkerMethod().
1              5            Completed WorkerMethod().
2              7            Completed work.
1              5            Completed work.
```

How can the 2nd invocation finish before the 1st? I thought every method call was to be sequential. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you Join created thread in Start method? If not it just starts worker and finishes so other request can be processed while your worker thread is running. `InstnaceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode` affect only service thread, not threads started from your service's operations. So if your operation do not wait for worker completion you can invoke operation several times before first worker finish his job.

Comment: Yes, I think that was the problem. The WCF InstanceContext and Concurrency mode only control the service thread but my worker manager is spawning off worker threads which I need to manage myself.